# In App Purchase and Apple Review

Tags: ios, app-store, in-app-purchase

I am trying to add in-app purchasing to an ios application which has been available on ios since 2010. According to Apple, I must submit my first in-app feature along with submitting an update to the application. The problem is that I can't test the in-app purchasing process in my code until the in-app feature is listed on the App Store. But Apple won't list the in-app feature on the App Store until they approve the product update. This is a very bad Catch-22. In my most recent attempt (third try), I put draft, untested code in the product to handle the in-app purchase. But of course I can't test it until Apple puts the feature to be in-app purchased on the price list.

Am I missing something? The Apple Review people sent me to Apple Tech Support. The Apple Tech Support people sent me to Apple Review. Any ideas to work around their Catch-22?

Comment: I tried testing in the sandbox, and also as a test user, but the add-in feature is still not shown as available. The SKProductsRequest Delegate returns an empty set of product/features from the App Store.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to implement the In App Purchase system into your app version as well as creating an iAP item in iTunes Connect, then use a Sandbox account to test purchasing of the content. The iAP doesn't have to be approved for that.

Sandbox accounts can be made in iTunes Connect under 'Manage Users'.

Comment: Yes, this solves the problem. While an In App Purchase item is pending approval (either waiting for review or under review) it can be tested in the Sandbox. In the Sandbox it will appear that it is on the App Store and all tests can be run.

Comment: If it's solved your issue, please mark my answer as the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Apple Docs: [Testing in the Sandbox](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/TestingInAppPurchases.html)

Comment: See comments on Sandbox testing below.

Comment: page not found :(